# Проблемы отображения директорий устройства в диалоге файлового менеджера

Tags: android, listview

Пытаюсь сделать файловый менеджер в диалоговом окне. Нашел [видеоролик](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NXYYdMVioQ0) где было показано как решить мою задачу. Все вроде как нужно но есть одна маленькая проблема - в списке который формируется из директорий в диалоговом окне каждый элемент состоит из полного пути к файлу/директории. Вот как это выглядит:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в коде формирование списка я так понимаю выглядит так:

```
fileList.add(file.getPath());
```

я пробовал обрезать строку которая добавляется в список на 20 символов. Все стало нормально выглядеть но после этого я не смог зайти в директорию чтобы посмотреть что там. Вероятнее всего я не смог этого сделать потому что при клике на элемент списка программа пыталась перейти по пути состоящему только из названия папки. Я вижу пока что только один вариант - при формировании списка отрезать 20 символов, а при попытке открыть папку лепить к названию папки эти обрезанные 20 символов чтобы можно было перейти по пути. Вот как выглядит весь код который создает это окошко:

```
@Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        Dialog dialog = null;
        switch (id) {
            case CUSTOM_DIALOG_ID:
                dialog = new Dialog(WriteResponseMess.this);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_layout);
                dialog.setTitle("Custom Dialog");
                dialog.setCancelable(true);
                dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);

                textFolder = dialog.findViewById(R.id.folder);
                buttonUp = dialog.findViewById(R.id.up);
                buttonUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        ListDir(curFolder.getParentFile());
                    }
                });


                dialog_ListView = dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialoglist);
                dialog_ListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                        File selected = new File(fileList.get(position));
                        if (selected.isDirectory()) {
                            ListDir(selected);
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(WriteResponseMess.this, selected.toString() + "selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });

                break;
        }

        return dialog;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPrepareDialog(int id, Dialog dialog) {
        super.onPrepareDialog(id, dialog);

        switch (id) {
            case CUSTOM_DIALOG_ID:
                ListDir(curFolder);
        }
    }

    void ListDir(File f) {
        if (f.equals(root)) {
            buttonUp.setEnabled(false);
        } else {
            buttonUp.setEnabled(true);
        }

        curFolder = f;
        textFolder.setText(f.getPath());

        File[] files = f.listFiles();
        fileList.clear();

        for (File file : files) {
            fileList.add(file.getPath());
        }

        ArrayAdapter<String> directoryList = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, fileList);
        dialog_ListView.setAdapter(directoryList);
    }
```

функция создания диалога вызывается при нажатии на кнопку.

### UPDATE

У меня получилось решить свою проблему, только тем способом который я придумал, другого я к сожалению не смог придумать, если у кого-то есть какие-то предложения то буду рад с ними ознакомится.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так будут показаны имена файлов и папок без путей:

```
void ListDir(File f) {
    ................

    String[] files = f.list();
    fileList.clear();

    // если доступ к содержимому папки запрещён - она вернёт null
    // обязательно проверяем! 
    if (files != null) {
        for (String file : files) {
            fileList.add(file);
        }
    }
    ArrayAdapter<String> directoryList = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, fileList);
    dialog_ListView.setAdapter(directoryList);
}
```

Чтобы правильно открывалось создаём файл из текущей папки и имени

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
    File selected = new File(curFolder, fileList.get(position));
    ....
```

Comment: пишу вам с другой темы (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/906848) с просьбой опубликовать ваш комментарий ("отдайте ссылку фрагменту и пусть он сам её загружает сразу в нужную вью в методе onCreateView. По-хорошему надо отдать ему элемент массива и пусть он по нему строит свой вид, если элемент содержит только данные для фрагмента.") в виде ответа, чтобы я могла его указать как правильный. Ваш комментарий оказался абсолютно правильным и решающим мой вопрос.

Comment: @InnaAhtina, чтобы обратиться к участнику форума достаточно упомянуть его ник через `@` в любом вопросе. По теме: вопрос стоит иначе и контекст, в котором коммент был актуален, потерялся с удалённым ответом. Поэтому для других людей ответ будет выглядеть неадекватно. Если есть желание поделиться решением - добавьте подробности в вопрос и опубликуйте "автоответ" с актуальным кодом (по возможности). Я за циферками не страдаю))) - взаимовыручка и вклад в доступность полезной информации важнее.